# Meteor import LESS files per layout

Tags: meteor, less, meteor-blaze

I've got a meteor project with a few different blaze layout templates and I'd like for them to each have their own LESS stylesheets. How do I import them on a per-layout basis, i.e. not importing them all in the main.less file?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach is to literally import them from your template js files like so:

```
// File layout.html
<template name="layout">
  <div class="layout-wrapper">
  </div>
</template>

// File layout.less
.layout-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

// File layout.js
import './layout.html';
import './layout.less';

Template.layout.onCreated(function () {
  // etc...
});
```

Now when you load the template's `layout.js` file, either by eager loading, imports, or dynamic imports, it will insert the compiled less to the page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in production, Meteor concatenates all the CSS into one big file, so you can't attach a specific file only to one template.

I got around this by basically defining an automatic wrapper div like so:

1. In your router, define a default layout e.g. in ironRouter:

   > ```
   > Router.configure({
   >     layoutTemplate: 'mainLayout',
   > });
   > ```
2. In your mainLayout template, create a wrapping div something like this:

   > ```
   > <div class="custom-page-wrapper-{{currentRouteName}}">
   >     {{> yield}}
   > </div>
   > ```
3. Define a global currentRouteName helper like this:

   > ```
   > UI.registerHelper("currentRouteName",function(){
   >     return Router.current() ? Router.current().route.getName() : "";
   > });
   > ```

With that, every template that uses this layout template will automatically be wrapped in a div with a custom-page-wrapper-XXXX class that is unique to each template and based on the route's name (which is guaranteed to be unique or else ironRouter will raise an error).

After that, you can specify any template-specific styling within that class in any LESS file you want.

Although this isn't exactly the same as specifying a different file for each template, it functionally accomplishes the same thing with the only expense being an extra wrapper div.